# Reconfigure jquery preload for image used as div background

Tags: jquery, background, preloader

I'm using this basic preloader which works great to load images to be used in an image tag. But I'd like to reconfigure it to load images that will be used as the backgrounds of divs, and then display the divs when the images are loaded

```
(function($) {
var imgList = [];
$.extend({
preload: function(imgArr, option) {
    var setting = $.extend({
        init: function(loaded, total) {},
        loaded: function(img, loaded, total) {},
        loaded_all: function(loaded, total) {}
    }, option);
    var total = imgArr.length;
    var loaded = 0;

    setting.init(0, total);
    for(var i in imgArr) {
        imgList.push($("<img />")
            .attr("src", imgArr[i])
            .load(function() {
                loaded++;
                setting.loaded(this, loaded, total);
                if(loaded == total) {
                    setting.loaded_all(loaded, total);
                }
            })
        );
    }

}
});
})(jQuery);

$(function() {

$.preload([
    "img/someImage.png"
], {
    init: function(loaded, total) {
    },
    loaded: function(img, loaded, total) {
    },
    loaded_all: function(loaded, total) {
    }
});

});
```

probably using the titles of the images (without extension) as the div id to make mapping them easy

```
<div id="someImage" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: I understand stripping the image src to get the tag to find and display the div. But I don't understand how imgList.push($("<img/>")... is working. It seems like it's built only to be useful to display <img> elements, and I don't know how to be sure it would actually be helping if I did the name-stripping-div-display I described. @servarevitas3

Comment: .push is a javascript command that adds an element to the end of an array and returns the new count. it seems like it's creating an array of img tags with the sources filled in.

Comment: @servarevitas3 -that process seems unnecessary, but I can't think of an alternative. The divs will have already been created so I don't want to alter the code to create divs with style='background... I'm wondering how best to alter the code to make sure the images are loaded into wherever the divs, when shown, will look for them to render (the cache I think??)